# how can i solve UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Before I start node.js, I already did mongod and mongo on PowerShell (I'm using Windows) with no error.

db.js code:

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/wetube");
```

but every time I start, this error occurs.

[image]

Comment: ECONNREFUSED means the operating system actively rejected the connection because there was nothing listening on that port.

Comment: Please refrain from providing the error message as an image and add it as a code block to your question